# TypeError: request.getHeader is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, raspberry-pi

I am trying to get header of get request.
But i receive the error:

```
TypeError: request.getHeader is not a function
    at Server.<anonymous> (/home/pi/progs/smarthome/Site/cpu.js:8:27)
    at Server.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:695:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:111:17)
```

here is my code:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs =  require("fs");

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    var temp = fs.readFileSync("/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp");
    var temp_c = temp/1000;

    var header = request.getHeader('Content-Type');
    console.log(header);

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Raspberry Pi cpu temperature: ");
    response.write("\n" + temp);
    response.write("\n" + temp_c);
    response.end();
});
server.listen(8080);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your req.getHeader() is not working because there is no method inside the incoming http message object. You are getting  an http.IncomingMessage object which does not have a req.getHeader(). [Doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage)

Comment: Thx, it`s working, i solved it with console.log(request.headers);

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these worked for me. I was trying to access a header inside a NextJS Serverless Function, on Vercel. Instead, I was able to get the header with this:

```
req.headers['header_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted of using getHeader, you can use :

```
 var header = request.header.get('Content-Type');
console.log(header);
```

Comment: I`m getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: And i ran this code on my pc with latest node.js and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

`req.headers['header_name']` really works and the reason is following:

As Ashish Rawat mentioned above in your `http.createServer(function(request, response)...` construction the 'request' is not `http.ClientRequest` but `http.IncomingMessage` class instance.

So `http.ClientRequest.getHeader()` method can't be applied here. Instead there's `http.IncomingMessage.headers` object. The reason why the way to access 'content-type' key is so unusial is '-' symbol in the middle of 'content-type'. You can access any other key without '-' as usual: `req.headers.host`, `req.headers.connection`, `req.headers.origin`, but in other cases it would be `req.headers['bla-bla']` instead: `req.headers['content-length']`, `req.headers['content-type']`, `req.headers['user-agent']` etc.